# How can i present items from an NgFor one step at a time on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an ngfor, with 3 items, and i would like to present them in steps, like questions in a form. For example, only showing the second question of the form, once the first step is answered.

I have an stackblitz code too see as reference.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oauzgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that ngFor is the best way to do that, anyway you can add

```
<tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index">
   <td *ngIf="i > currentIndex">{{hero.name}}</td>
   User do something and you increase the currentIndex
</tr>
```

In the ts you only need to declare the currentIndex and set it to 0 at init and a method to increase the index called by the html in the Do something block

Comment: How? If i do an increment on click, it will keep adding numbers to the property, so if i click on the first item 3 items, it will display 3 steps.

Comment: I modified you stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsmp13?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yeah, thats what i did here, but thats broken tough, the first box should only show the second one, even if clicked twice, and the second one, show the third.

Comment: Then send the index to your function and set the currentIndex to that index + 1, somethign like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsmp13?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: i've also tried this heheh, but then, if i click on the first box, after the third one is shown, it will erase the third one.. i wonder if theres a way to only increment, and never to decrease the currentIndex count

Comment: Then only increase the index if the user is clicking on the last div, something like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsmp13?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: ooo, the link with  the code doesnt work, but the logic does make sense! so what i need is a way to figure out if the click happened on the last div of the ngFor, and then increment

Comment: Sorry I created the link without saving. Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsmp13?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It woooooooorks! your're a god sent! thanks!